# Spring Integration - Two Transformers For Same Method Which Annotated With @Transformer Notation

Tags: spring-integration, transformer-model

I have a method which annotated with @Transformer notation. But, in other case needs to use this this transformer for different input and output channels. Let's think that I have a code like this:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "myInputChannel", outputChannel = "myOutputChannel")
public Message<List<DataElement>> transformMyBusiness(Message<byte[]> message) throws Throwable {
    Message<List<CustomDataType>> incomingMessage = doAJob(message);
    return incomingMessage;
}
```

I have another input channel which is myInputChannel2 and output channel myOutputChannel2. These input and output channels will use the above transformer but I don't want to duplicate that code.

How can I use same method for two transformers with @Transformer annotation?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible now like this:

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = "myInputChannel", outputChannel = "myOutputChannel")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "myInputChannel2", outputChannel = "myOutputChannel2")
public Message<List<DataElement>> transformMyBusiness(Message<byte[]> message) throws Throwable {
```

There is no `@Repeatable` support for these annotations yet, but we really have it in mind: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2708.

Perhaps it's time to give it a short again...